# Update a datastore entity - change ancestor without changing entity key

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, go

Is it possible to update the ancestor of an entity without changing the entity key?  How would I accomplish that in Go?

I have a hierarchy similar to this:

Company/Department/Employee

It started off with no department for the employee: Company/Employee.
Then later when he/she gets assigned to a department, I want to change it to: Company/Department/Employee, but I want the entity key to remain the same as it is already  used elsewhere to reference this entity.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to update the ancestor of an entity without changing the entity key?

I don't believe so. The ancestor is part of the key.

> How would I accomplish that in Go?

Do you need to use an Entity Group here? I try to avoid entity group whenever possible. They add too many restrictions. I would suggest that you add properties to your Employee entity for Company and Department:

```
type Employee struct {
  Company, Department string
}
```

You can still query by these properties, although there maybe a few second delay after they are updated. If you need strong consistency you can always look the Employee up by Key. That will always return the most uptodate version.

Comment: Correct, you cannot change the ancestor without changing the key.